# Customize angular layout breakpoints

Tags: angular, angular-material, breakpoints

I'm currently working on a site's responsiveness and one of the requirements is to have content centered after the screen gets to 1600px, which is not a breakpoint predefined in Angular cdk layout, trying to have a custom breakpoint at that width so the breakpoint observer adjusts to the specific css code for that layout, currently have this on the ts file and the current solution only works if the page is reloaded when the screen is above 1600px

```
  this.breakpointObserver.observe([Breakpoints.Handset,
  Breakpoints.HandsetLandscape,
  Breakpoints.HandsetPortrait,])
  .subscribe(result => {

    this.handsetView = false;
    this.widescreenView = false;
    const breakpoints = result.breakpoints;

    if (breakpoints[Breakpoints.Handset] || breakpoints[Breakpoints.HandsetLandscape]
      || breakpoints[Breakpoints.HandsetPortrait]) {
      this.handsetView = true;  
      console.log("screens matches handset");
    }
    else if (this.breakpointObserver.isMatched('(min-width: 1600px)')){
      console.log('widescreen');
      this.widescreenView = true;
    }    
  });
```

since it's not one of the predefined breakpoints it won't adjust when going from less than 1600px to 1600px and above, guess just need a way for that 1600px mark to be observed. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does it have to be done with Angular? You can do it with CSS like: `@media only screen and (max-width: 1600px) {...}`   . Also, do you have a StackBlitz link that you could provide? Thanks

Comment: Original requirement was to move away from media queries and move towards breakpoints, we originally had it with media queries, but this may change a bit since we need to have this done and I've been looking around and so far the only thing I've found is to do it with the queries. And no sorry don't have a StackBlitz link as of now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was going about it wrong, in case anyone wants to know the answer or it's helpful for someone, there's no need to create a new breakpoint or edit, you can set a specific width to the breakpoint observer so it observes that specific width, this worked for me

```
this.breakpointObserver.observe([Breakpoints.Handset,
Breakpoints.HandsetLandscape,
Breakpoints.HandsetPortrait,
'(min-width: 1600px)'])
.subscribe(result => {

this.handsetView = false;
this.widescreenView = false;
const breakpoints = result.breakpoints;

if (breakpoints[Breakpoints.Handset] || 
breakpoints[Breakpoints.HandsetLandscape]
  || breakpoints[Breakpoints.HandsetPortrait]) {
  this.handsetView = true;  
  console.log("screens matches handset");
}
else if (this.breakpointObserver.isMatched('(min-width: 1600px)')){
  console.log('widescreen');
  this.widescreenView = true;
}    
});
```